# script Project disapeared from My Projects Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, ide

Until very recently I would run a script on a Google Sheet with a Time Trigger to update the data on the sheet. Since I started to have problem with the data, I went on the Apps Script panel "My Triggers" to remove the time triggers in order to fix the script and the data on the sheet. After removing the triggers, I was unable to find the script in "My Projects". I searched every page and looked into the trash, but I can't find my script anymore.

Could anyone please help me restore the script ?

Comment: Go to the sheet where your script is bound to and go to tools => script editor

Comment: Hi Mario, when I do this, it opens the Apps Script Editor where I was used to see the scripts that I wrote related to the sheet, but instead it opens an "Untitled project" and all the previous scripts related the sheet disapeared.

Comment: It looks that when you tried to delete the triggers you actually deleted the script. AFAIK there is no way to recover a deleted bounded script.

Answer (score 0):

Once a bounded script has been deleted there is not way to recover it (they don't go to the trash).

If you are a Google Workspace client, you can [contact their support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en).

Also, if you can reproduce it reliably, you should [report it on Google Issue Tracker (Apps Script component)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905).